# magento target rule not applying to a specific product

Tags: magento, target, rule

A simple product is in specific category other products have that rule applied.This is happening on magento enterprise 1.13.0.1 version.
A rule is applicable to that category but when I look in catalogrule_product table then there is no entry for that product. This means no rule applies to that product.

http://www.solvingmagento.com/quick-tip-magento-catalog-price-rules-dont-work/  is the link I refered.

I want to know if for some reason a product has no target rules applied then:
1. Is there no cron job that will handle this and populate catalogrule_product table.
If yes then which cron job does this.

1. Also when we saved product its expected that catalog_product_save_after event should get fired resulting in Mage_CatalogRule module’s observer method applyAllRulesOnProduct getting executed but still no luck.
2. When I click via admin apply rule then it works.

I want to know is has magento not provided any cron job/indexer to handle this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating products outside of the magento backend (using php, or soap) you may have to use the following code after you have called the $product->save() method...

```
 public function applyActiveRulesToProduct($productId)
    {
        try {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') -> load($productId);

            $rules = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);

            foreach ($rules as $rule) {
                $rule->applyAllRulesToProduct($product);
            }
            return "Applied rules to " . $productId;

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }


    }
```

It is code that i wrote for my own soap api extension.  I could not get the rules to apply using applyToProduct(product, websiteIds) but using applyAllRulesToProduct with filters on the rules array seems to do the trick.

FYI, this code is buried inside of the CatalogRule.Rule.php core code as well, but it cannot be called directly using the rule model or product model.  Who knows why they did that.